# await expression is only allowed within an async function

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, async-await, ionic3

Could you tell me where to put `async` keyword? I have tried many places.But same error.

```
  async addNewCategory() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({ 
      title: 'New Category',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name',
          placeholder: 'Category',
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Done',
          handler: (data:Category) => {
            if (data.name != '') {
              //Error shows here
              await this.categoryProvider.isCategoryAlreadyExist(data.name, this.projectId); 
            } else {
              this.showToast.showErrorToast('Invalid Category');
              return false;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: `async (data:Category) => {...`

Comment: Tried. It shows this error. `[ts]
         Type '{ text: string; handler: (data: Category) => Promise<false>; }' is not assignable to type 'AlertButton'.
            Types of property 'handler' are incompatible.
              Type '(data: Category) => Promise<false>' is not assignable to type '(value: any) => boolean | void'.
                Type 'Promise<false>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | void'.
                  Type 'Promise<false>' is not assignable to type 'void'.
(property) handler: (data: Category) => Promise<false>
` @deezg

Comment: @Sampath Well yes, it looks like whereever you pass this object does not support asynchronous handlers.

Comment: Oh.. :( Could you tell me workaround then? @Bergi

Comment: @Sampath No idea. Check the documentation for that `AlertButton` thing.

Comment: Is `categoryProvider` a `@Injectable()` angular service?

Comment: Yes, It is a `service` or `provider`. @PatrykBrejdak

Comment: it seems to be a type declaration issue of alert in ionic 2+ check [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12675)

Comment: Oh.. This is great. Hope you can put it as a workaround. I mean use traditional callback method instead of `async`. I forgot it completely :D Thanks :) @SurajRao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you use

```
async (data:Category) => {...}
```

as mentioned in the comments. But the current alertController does not take an `async handler` because of its type definitions as per this [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12675).

```
export interface AlertButton {
  text?: string;
  role?: string;
  cssClass?: string;
  handler?: (value: any) => boolean|void;
}
```

Alert Button definition [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/alert/alert-options.ts).

You will need to use the more traditional way of using `then`.

```
handler: (data:Category) => {
            if (data.name != '') {
              //Error shows here
              this.categoryProvider.isCategoryAlreadyExist(data.name, this.projectId)
                .then(()=>alert.dismiss()); 
            } else {
              this.showToast.showErrorToast('Invalid Category');
              return false;
            }
          }
```